# how to create something like For All Seasons app in opengl?

Tags: objective-c, iphone, opengl-es, core-animation

I have seen a free app named For All Seasons. It has very cool effects. Does someone know how we can achieve this using OpenGL or Core Graphics?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the [original version](http://www.hahakid.net/forallseasons/forallseasons.html) also runs on Windows, it is not using Core Animation.

But you can use CA for 3D graphics to create similar effects - 
Take a look at [this tutorial](http://watchingapple.com/2008/04/core-animation-3d-perspective/) (it is for the Mac but the principles mentioned there also apply for the iPhone).
If you want to use typography effects as "For all Seasons" does, Core Animation is the better choice because it comes with font rendering support. (I think you still have to use font textures when working with OpenGL ES - but I am not sure about that)